# Problem Using Mathematical Keyboard in Math StackExchange

Tags: support

I am new in this site. I want to use Math StackExchange. But I don't know how to ask question using mathematical symbols. Those who know how to ask math question, please help me.

Comment: See [FAQ for math.stackexchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117) and [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Online LaTeX Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).

You can write your problem there and it will create the LaTeX code for you to post on the Math.SE.

It helped me a lot when I first started, and even  now sometimes, I use it.

It is available in ~20 languages as well!